# Areas in asp.net mvc, only one work at time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, areas

My folder look like this:

- (root)/Areas/Admin/Views/..
- (root)/Areas/Admin/Controllers/...
- (root)/Areas/Admin/Routes.cs
- (root)/Areas/Forum/Views/..
- (root)/Areas/Forum/Controllers/...
- (root)/Areas/Forum/Routes.cs

  ```
  public class Routes : AreaRegistration
  ```

  {
      public override string AreaName
      {
          get { return "Admin"; }
      }

  ```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
  {
      context.MapRoute(
          "Admin_Default",
          "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
          new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", Id = (string)null }
      );
  }
  ```

  }

  public class Routes : AreaRegistration
  {
      public override string AreaName
      {
          get { return "Forum"; }
      }

  ```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext routes)
  {
      routes.MapRoute(
          "Forum_Default",
          "{controller}/{action}",
          new { controller = "Forum", action = "Index"}
      );
  }
  ```

  }

Global.asax

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The startpage should be Home/Index but it start with Admin/Index, why?

Only site.com/Admin works not site.com/Forum

How should i get Admin and Forum Areas to work right? Why is only Admin working and not Forum?

When i delete Admin/Routes.cs file Forum start to work...

**EDIT:**

Home in ~/Views/ don't show as startpage even if i have

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
```

in my Global.asax after AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your area mappings should be structured like so.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_Default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
        new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", Id = (string)null }
    );
}
```

and

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Forum_Default",
        "Forum/{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
         new { controller = "Forum", action = "Index"}
    );
}
```

Keeps your routes from conflicting, which is what i think is happening in your case. As your default route matches your admin route.