# Asp.net MVC 2 Areas. Only one will work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

This is my goal:

I need to two (or more) "Areas" for my MVC web app. They would be accessed like so:

```
/* Home */
http://example.com/
http://example.com/about
http://example.com/faq
http://example.com/contact

/* Admin */
http://example.com/admin
http://example.com/admin/login
http://example.com/admin/account
http://example.com/admin/ect
```

I would *like* to organize the project like the following:

```
MyExampleMVC2AreasProject/
    Areas/
        Admin/
            Controllers/
            Models/
            Views/
                Home/
                Shared/
                    Site.Master
                Web.Config
            AdminAreaRegistration.cs
        Web/
            Controllers/
            Models/
            Views/
                Home/
                Shared/
                    Site.Master
                Web.Config
            WebAreaRegistration.cs
    Global.asax
    Web.Config
```

So, in `Global.asax` I have:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults

        );
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Here is `WebAreaRegistration.cs`

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyExampleMVC2AreasProject.Areas.Web
{
    public class WebAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Web";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "WebDefault",
                "{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

'AdminAreadRegistration.cs' is set up the same but the url param is `Admin/{action}/{id}`.

With the setup above the `Web` "Area" works great (example.com/about, example.com/contact, etc).

**What do I need to do to get the `Admin` "Area" hooked up with the routes the way I want them?** I just get `404`ed now.
I've tried every combination of routes, routes w/namespaces, URL Parameters, parameter defaults, etc, I could think of. *I have a feeling I'm missing something pretty basic.*

Comment: Looks like a solution has already been posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721604/areas-in-asp-net-mvc-only-one-work-at-time

Comment: That will let me set it so that I can access both `example.com/web` and `example.com/admin` but not `example.com` (example.com should be the `Web` area). How can I route `Web` to the root?

Comment: I managed to do it. Its VERY hackish though: http://notesforit.blogspot.com/2010/08/default-area-mvc-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is here: http://notesforit.blogspot.com/2010/08/default-area-mvc-2.html

I don't like it and would love to get a better solution.

-- copied from URL above:

Implement your Areas as usually, register any routes that you need.

For example:

```
public class PublicAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
    public override string AreaName
    {
      get
      {
        return "Public";
      }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.MapRoute(
        "Public_default",
        "Public/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, }
      );
    }
  }
```

And:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
    public override string AreaName
    {
      get
      {
        return "Admin";
      }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Overview", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
  }
```

**It's important, that URL should have any prefix, for example http://site.com/PREFIX/{controller}/{action}, because prefix of default `Area` will be cropped**

Next in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  public static string _defaultAreaKey = "DefaultArea";

  public static void RegisterDefaultRoute(RouteCollection routes)
  {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //reading parameter DefaultArea from web.config 
    string defaultArea = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[_defaultAreaKey];

    //check for null
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultArea)) 
      throw new Exception("Default area isn\'t set");

    //select routes from registered, 
    //which have DataTokens["area"] == DefaultArea
    //Note, each Area might have more than one route
    var defRoutes = from Route route in routes
            where
            route.DataTokens != null &&
            route.DataTokens["area"] != null && 
            route.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == defaultArea
            select route;


    //cast to array, for LINQ query will be done,
    //because we will change collection in cycle
    foreach (var route in defRoutes.ToArray())
    {
      //Important! remove from routes' table
      routes.Remove(route);

      //crop url to first slash, ("Public/", "Admin/" etc.)
      route.Url = route.Url.Substring(route.Url.IndexOf("/") + 1);

      //Important! add to the End of the routes' table
      routes.Add(route);
    }      
  }

  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    //register all routes
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    //register default route and move it to end of table
    RegisterDefaultRoute(RouteTable.Routes);      
  }
}
```

Do not forget add parameter to web.config:

```
<configuration>

 <appSettings>
  <add key="DefaultArea" value="Public"/>
 </appSettings>

<!-- ALL OTHER-->
</configuration>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could replicate your answer here so that in case your blog goes down, we don't have a dead answer.

Comment: will do. Although that isn't my blog.  :-p

Answer (score 0):

I use [this AreaRegistrationUtil class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496956/providing-or-filtering-assemblies-when-registering-areas-for-an-asp-net-mvc-2-0-a/2715148#2715148).  It automatically registers anything which inherits AreaRegistration in any assembly you specify.  As an added bonus, it's WAY faster than `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas` because it only looks at the assembly you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your namespaces on all your area registrations.

### Example

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "MyExampleMVC2AreasProject.Areas.Admin.Controllers" } // This is area namespace
);
```